# Obtaining metric and compatible differential equations on codimension one foliation of $n$-cube

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, linear-pde, foliations, information-geometry

Essentially the same content as this post on Math stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4741835/460999. I don't expect an answer there and after waiting a few days I've decided to post here. I'm in my 20's and I would say, and I think others would agree, that I'm very weak in mathematics (I think my level is beginner undergraduate level) so please try to tailor your answers to a level I can understand. Thanks so much.

Let $M=(0,1)^n$ and take $(M,g_n)$ where $g_n$ is the usual Euclidean metric. Let's assume that in dim. $n$ we want a smooth codimension one foliation of $M$ whose disjoint union of $1$ dim. leaves $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f_{\alpha}  \simeq S^{n-2} \times (0,\sqrt{n})=S$ and where each $1$-leaf limits to points $p,q$ s.t. $\mathrm{dist}_n(p,q)=\sqrt{n}.$ In other words the mutually diffeomorphic surfaces of the class $S$ accumulate to $p$ and $q.$ Just to note: in dimension $n=3$ there will be a degenerate cylinder, one with zero volume, and therefore the foliation here will be "singular," that is, one leaf will not be codimension one.

Say we want a sequence of projections $(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)\mapsto (x^1,x^2,...,x^{n-1})\mapsto ... \mapsto (x^1,x^2)$ which send $1$-leaves in higher dimensional space to one lower dimension at each step. In the case of $(x^1,x^2,x^3)\mapsto(x^1,x^2)$ we have $1$-leaves in $(0,1)^3$ mapped down to the plane.

Let's begin in dim. $n=2,$ with $p=(0,1)$ and $q=(1,0).$ Define a canonical foliation of $(0,1)^2$ as follows: $\varphi_s(x):=\exp\big(\frac{s}{\log x}\big).$ This foliation solves a linear parabolic diffusion equation:

$$ s \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\varphi_s(x) = -x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\varphi_s(x) \tag{1} $$

Define a $1$-parameter family of  Riemannian metrics which will be used to measure the distance between two leaves in this foliation as:

$$ g_s(r)=\int_{(0,1)} x^{r-1}\varphi_s(x)~dx = 2\sqrt{\frac{s}{r}}K_1(2\sqrt{sr}).$$

For Bessel function $K.$

For example the discrete distance between leaf $s=1$ and leaf $s=2$ would be a subtraction of integrals:

$$d(1,2)= \bigg| g_1(r)-g_2(r) \bigg | $$

Now, we have a way of recording distances between leaves on the plane, precisely we've decided to measure "areas" between these leaves, and a differential equation that tells us a diffusion relationship between leaves. One might like to preserve these structures when lifting onto the mutually diffeomorphic class of surfaces $S.$

First, we note that $g_s(r)$ also respects a partial differential equation and we can use this geometric flow to figure out what it might look like on the curved class of surfaces, $S.$ This differential equation is third order and linear (it can be reduced to second order through the Fourier transform):

$$ s^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial s^3}g_s(r)=r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}g_s(r) \tag{2}$$

I think we need a $1$-leaf to sweep out an area, $a$ on each $S$ which mutually projects onto the plane region which sweeps out an area of $a$. This corresponds to the projection map being area preserving. In other words we need an isometry.

One crucial thing to define are the "zonoid-like" regions, which are the area bounded by any two leaves $\varphi_{s_1}$ and $\varphi_{s_2}$ s.t. $s_1s_2=1$ and this includes the boundary leaves. This is very helpful because as $\varphi_{s_1}$ deforms into $\varphi_{s_2}$ and back into $\varphi_{s_1}$ the corresponding surface $S$, its $1$-leaf, has now swept out an area that is equal to the total surface area of $S,$ or in other words the $1$-leaf is a generator of $S.$ It also gives a diameter for each surface $S$.

> Essentially my question is: How does the calculation go to obtain a metric on the class $S$ surfaces compatible with $g_s(r)$ and is it reasonable to expect the projection to map areas on the surface of $S$ to equal areas on the base manifold? Is it reasonable to expect the foliation by the $S$ class to also obey a PDE that reduces to $(1)?$

Comment: You first mention a codimension-1 foliation and then discuss 1-dimensional leaves. Where do the 1-dimensional leaves come from and how are they connected to the codimension-1 foliation (assuming the big dimension n ≠ 2) ?

Comment: @DanielAsimov I appreciate the comment - The codimension 1 foliation is broken down into 1 dim. leaves, for each leaf in the codimension 1 foliation. We have $f_{\alpha}$ s.t. $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f_{\alpha}  \simeq S^{n-2} \times (0,\sqrt{n})=S$. You could think of this as space curves in $(0,1)^3$ anchored to $p,q$, but where the space curves fit into equivalence classes, and those equivalence classes precisely form the class of mutually diffeomorphic surfaces $S.$ (Here $S$ is different than $S^n$ by the way).

Comment: But you have never defined the set A. Are you referring to the curves that are orthogonal to the codimension-1 leaves?

Comment: That's a good point. Since on the 2d space we have a real parameter $s$ which indexes the leaves, then it should match up with the big dimension. So, it should be $s \in \Bbb R_+$ as opposed to $A$.

Comment: @DanielAsimov no, I'm not referring to the curves that are orthogonal to the codimension 1 leaves